# Swift Combine equivalent to concatMap

Tags: swift, combine

What's the Combine's equivalent to [concatMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap)? I want to keep the order of downstream items to be the same as the original upstream items

```
[1,2,3].publisher.flatMap { self.getItem($0) } // This does not guarantee [Item1, Item2, Item3]
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but why aren't you using `compactMap`? I'm pretty sure `flatMap` was deprecated.

Comment: [According to this cheatsheet](https://github.com/CombineCommunity/rxswift-to-combine-cheatsheet), there is no equivalent. You'd need to build it yourself.